# How to call decoded json field values in view in yii 1

Tags: php, json, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my controller:

```
$model=ChForms::model()->findByPk($id);
$decode= $model->json;
$res=CJSON::decode($decode);
var_dump($res);
return $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model, 'res'=>$res));
```

the result of `var_dump($res)` is:

```
["p_2"]=> string(4) "test" ["p_3"]=> string(1) "0"
```

How can I call values of `["p_2"]` and `["p_3"]` in my view(e.g test, 0)

Comment: You can decode the JSON to an array. To do so, call json_decode($decode, true).

Answer (score 1):

[`CJSON::decode()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON/#decode-detail) returns an array by default. Since you are passing `$res` into your view you can access the required fields via `$res["p_2"]` and `$res["p_3"]`.